# Characterization of $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ norm?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, variational-analysis

I can't understand why $\|g\|_{H_{\partial}^{1/2}} = \|u\|_{H^1} $ where $u$ solves the problem
\begin{equation*}
- \Delta u + u = 0, \quad \Omega\\
u|_{\partial \Omega} = g
\end{equation*}

The weak form should be to find $w \in H^1_0$:

\begin{equation*}
(w,v)_{H^1} = -(G, v)_{H^1} , \quad \forall v \in H^1_0
\end{equation*}

where $ u = w+G$ and $G$ is the lifting of $g$.

$(.,.)_{H^1}$ is the $H^1$ inner-product.

Now I can only get this estimate from the Lax-Milgram lemma:

$$
\|u\| -\|G\| \leq \|w\| \leq \|G\|
$$

And so:

$$
\|g\| \leq \|u\| \leq 2\|g\|
$$

As the $H^{1/2}$ norm is the $\inf$

But how to get equality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $H^{1/2}(\Gamma):=\gamma_0(H^1(\Omega))$, where $\gamma_0(u):=u|_{\partial \Omega } $. Then we have that $\ker \gamma = H_0^1(\Omega)$. By the orthogonal descomposition $H^1(\Omega) = H^1_0(\Omega) \oplus H_0^1(\Omega)^{\perp}$.  The restricted trace operator $\tilde {\gamma}_0:H_0^1(\Omega)^{\perp} \to H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$ is a linear isomorphism.

Now for any $g \in H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$ there is a $u = u_0+u^{\perp} \in H^1_0(\Omega) \oplus H_0^1(\Omega)^{\perp}$  with $g = \gamma_0(u)$. In particular $g=\gamma_0(u^{\perp})$, immediately we obtain $\tilde{\gamma}_0^{-1}(g)=u^{\perp}$, then

$$\|g\|_{1/2} = \inf_{u \in H^1(\Omega):\gamma_0(u)=g} \|u\|_{H^1}= \inf_{u \in H^1(\Omega):\gamma_0(u)=g} \|u_0+\tilde{\gamma}^{-1}(g)\|_{H^1}.$$
This infimum reachs when $u_0=0$, then
$$\|g\|_{1/2} = \|\tilde{\gamma}^{-1}(g)\|_{H^1}=\|u^{\perp}\|_{H^1}$$

Finally, is not too complicate to show that $u^{\perp}$ is the weak solution, because
\begin{align}
H_0^1(\Omega)^{\perp} & = \{u^{\perp}:\int_{\Omega}(u^{\perp}w+\nabla u^{\perp}\cdot \nabla w ) = 0 \quad \forall w \in H^1_0(\Omega) \} \\
&= \{u^{\perp} \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega):-\Delta u^{\perp}+u=0\}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, do you recommend any books to learn about this kind of stuff, preferably with proofs?

Comment: *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations* is an standard book, but I'm using a book in spanish about Sobolev Spaces. However the autor has a very similar book in english, with an stronger use of Sobolev spaces at work called  *Gatica - A Simple Introduction to the Mixed Finite Element Method* Additionally take a look to *Mclean - Strongly Elliptic Systems and Boundary Integral Equations*.